# Electric behavior of dollar sign using AUCTeX

Tags: latex, auctex, electric-pair-mode

I'm trying to turn `$...$` into an electric pair, just as say `(...)`.
So I tried [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75697/auctex-how-to-cause-math-mode-dollars-to-be-closed-automatically-with-electric), and it works fine on my older machine, running Emacs 24.3.1 and AUCTeX 11.87.
However, on a newer installation (Emacs 24.5.1, AUCTeX 12.1.1), it doesn't quite behave like it should.
When I type `$x+y$`, it should be giving me

`$x+y$^`,

where `^` denotes point. But instead I get

`$x+y$^$$`.

Obviously, Emacs fails to move over the automatically-inserted closing `$` and instead inserts a new pair.
Here is the relevant part of my `.emacs`:

```
(electric-pair-mode 1)
(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "$") 'self-insert-command)
(push '(?\$ . ?\$) electric-pair-pairs)
```

The `push` line may be included or not, it doesn't make a difference.
I also tried the following `.emacs`, as suggested by the AUCTeX manual:

```
(electric-pair-mode 1)
(set (make-variable-buffer-local 'TeX-electric-math) (cons "$" "$"))
```

This gives me `$x+y$^$`, which is not much better.
How do I get the behavior I want?

Comment: I'm electric-pair-mode's author. This seems to be a bug.  Can you report it via `M-x report-emacs-bug`?

Comment: I just reported it as you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I explained in my comment, this is a bug.  Until it is fixed, you can work around it like so

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          'fix-electric-pair-paired-delimiters-in-tex-mode)

(defun fix-electric-pair-paired-delimiters-in-tex-mode ()
  (add-function
   :around
   (local 'electric-pair-skip-self)
   (lambda (oldfun c)
     (pcase (electric-pair-syntax-info c)
       (`(,syntax ,_ ,_ ,_)
        (if (eq syntax ?$)
            (unwind-protect
                (progn
                  (delete-char -1)
                  (texmathp))
              (insert-char c))
          (funcall oldfun c)))))
   '((name . fix-electric-pair-paired-delimiters-in-tex-mode))))
```